# how to select few numbers from randomly generated numbers using C

Tags: c, random

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void main()
{
    int i,N;
    N=20;
    printf("Random data points are: \n");
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
         printf("%d \n", rand() %100);
    }
    getch();
}
```

suppose random data points are :
6
8
9
17
19
5
4
1
14
10
9
.upto 20..

how can i select 'k' numbers from this output generated by Rand function.
for example: 
if i take user input k=4 then the program must return 4 values from this output..

please guide me..thank u

Comment: do you want user input? you can use scanf.

Answer (score 2):

use `scanf("%d",&N);`

```
printf("Random data points are: \n");
scanf("%d",&N);
 for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
         printf("%d \n", rand() %100);
    }
```